# UIScrollView ContentSize Limited to the Size of the UIScollView

Tags: ios

I have set the contentSize of the UIScrollView as follows:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,800);
```

But as you can see in the image below it still displays one last line under the UITabbar. Why?

I am using iOS 7.[image]

Comment: try to decrease the value of 800 why because content size have greater than the screen size

Comment: @ernaidu I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: try for example **self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,750);**

Comment: try to change this self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,800);//  decrease the 800 to 700

Comment: Changing the 800 to 700 or 600 does not do anything!

Comment: first set the scroll view frame properly. It seems to be inproper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrollView's `contentSize` refers to the size of the content that can be scrolled through. For example you could have a `contentSize` height of 2000 px, because you have 2000 px worth of content to scroll through.

Your `contentSize` is not the problem; you indeed want it to be 800 (I'm assuming that's the height of all your text and graphics, not including the tab bar at the bottom.) What you want to change is the actual size of the scrollView object itself. Then the scrollView will be the correct height (something like `scrnHeight - tabBarHeight`) but the `contentSize` will still reflect the size of the *content* (the stuff *inside* the scrollView).

```
[self.scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.scrollView.frame.origin.x, 
    self.scrollView.frame.origin.Y, 320, scrnHeight - tabBarHeight)];
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 800);
```

And then you should be all set.  Now it's possible that 800 isn't actually the number you want; the number you want is the exact height from the top of the scrollview to the very botom of that text at the bottom. But this is the idea :)

Comment: Turns out it was a constraint that was causing the issue. I adjusted the constraint and now it is fine!